# How can I parse out get request parameters in spray-routing?

Tags: scala, httprequest, akka, spray

This is what the section of code looks like

```
    get{
      respondWithMediaType(MediaTypes.`application/json`){
          entity(as[HttpRequest]){
            obj => complete{


                println(obj)
                "ok"
            }
          }
      }
    }~
```

I can map the request to a spray.http.HttpRequest object and I can extract the uri from this  object but I imagine there is an easier way to parse out the parameters in a get request than doing it manually.

For example if my get request is

```
 http://localhost:8080/url?id=23434&age=24
```

I want to be able to get id and age out of this request

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Actually you can do this much much better. In routing there are two directives: `parameter` and `parameters`, I guess the difference is clear, you can also use some modifiers: `!` and `?`. In case of `!`, it means that this parameter must be provided or the request is going to be rejected and `?` returns an option, so you can provide a default parameter in this case. Example:

```
val route: Route = {
  (path("search") & get) {
    parameter("q"!) { query =>
      ....
    }
  }
}

val route: Route = {
  (path("search") & get) {
    parameters("q"!, "filter" ? "all") { (query, filter) => 
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is cleaner.

Comment: Note that on Spray 1.2 it would be `parameters('q, 'filter ? "all")`

Comment: @SamyDindane it doesn't matter, `NameReplacable` defined for strings as well as for symbols

Comment: What's the purpose of `"filter" ? "all"`? Could you please give an example? Thanks

Comment: @KevinMeredith Read it like `getOrElse` for the `Option` type. If there's no `filter` parameter in the request, the value for it will be `all`

Comment: Thanks. Also, you don't need to specify the query parameters' types? In your example, are the query parameters, `q` and `filter` assumed to be of type `String` since you did not specify a type?

Comment: using the latest akka 2.4.3 I get error when typing this code: `too many arguments for method parameters`. What has changed? Are the docs outdated?

Comment: @ecoe nothing, just checked and works fine, I bet you've missed some imports or the types are wrong

Comment: @4lex1v missed what imports? Could the code sample in your solution please explicitly define the necessary imports? I have a get request working perfectly, so if there are other implicit imports I need that is news to me and not discussed at all in the docs. Thanks for the quick response.

Comment: @ecoe In fact you are right, this sample is wrong in that you need to provide a required value for `!`, like `'q ! "default"`, which is required. I believe this is your problem