# How to read query parameters in akka-http?

Tags: scala, akka-stream, akka-http

I know akka-http libraries marshal and unmarshal to class type while processing request.But now, I need to read request-parameters of `GET` request. I tried `parameter()` method and It is returning `ParamDefAux` type but i need those values as strings types

I  check for answer at below questions.

1. [How can I parse out get request parameters in spray-routing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20011855/how-can-i-parse-out-get-request-parameters-in-spray-routing)
2. [Query parameters for GET requests using Akka HTTP (formally known as Spray)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31929843/query-parameters-for-get-requests-using-akka-http-formally-known-as-spray)

but can't do what i need.

Please tell me how can i extract query parameters from request. OR How can  I extract required value from `ParamDefAux`

Request URL

```
http://host:port/path?key=authType&value=Basic345
```

Get method definition

```
 val  propName = parameter("key")
 val  propValue = parameter("value")
 complete(persistanceMgr.deleteSetting(propName,propValue))
```

My method declarations

```
def deleteSetting(name:String,value:String): Future[String] = Future{
 code...
}
```

Comment: It should work, have you tried?     path("query") {
      parameters('name.as[String]) {name =>
        complete(name)
      }
    } ~

Answer (score 34, accepted):

For a request like `http://host:port/path?key=authType&value=Basic345` try

```
path("path") {
  get {
    parameters('key.as[String], 'value.as[String]) { (key, value) =>
      complete {
        someFunction(key,value)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: For this to work, `import akka.http.scaladsl.server.Directives._` needs to be there.

Comment: Is it normal practice to separate key value pairs as two separate query params (as shown in your example)? The alternative being that instead of having a query param called "key" we would just call it authType and have its value be Basic345

Comment: Is it possible to give the parameters default values?

Answer (score 1):

Even though being less explicit in the code, you can also extract all the query parameters at once from the context. You can use as follows:

```
// Previous part of the Akka HTTP routes ...
extract(_.request.uri.query()) { params  =>
  complete {
    someFunction(key,value)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wish extract `query parameters` as one piece

```
extract(ctx => ctx.request.uri.queryString(charset = Charset.defaultCharset)) { queryParams =>
   //useyourMethod()
}
```